# Why when I send 2 parameters to my firebase cloud function my token is automatically rejected?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angularfire

The process is as follows, I pass 2 parameters: lvlUser & uidUser,
I have an HTTP interceptor that when one authenticates, it automatically sends in the HTTP header my token, when all this is received by my firebase function, it first checks if the method is correct, then it must check if my token is not expired and has the correct level, then it checks if I have the parameters defined and correct, if all is ok then it executes the rest of my function,
the problem is that if I send it only one parameter it gets to the section that detects that a parameter is not defined, now if I send it 2 parameters, it gets stuck in the verification of my token, and always rejects it.

**function and params**

```
getEmployee(lvl: string, uid: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._httpClient.get('http', {params: {lvlUser, uidUser}, observe: 'response' })
    .pipe(
      map((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
    );
  }
```

**http interceptor**

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this._authenticated = this._authService._isLoggedIn();

    // Clone the request object
    let reqClone = req.clone();

    if (this._authenticated) {
        return from(this._authService._token()).pipe(
            map(_token => reqClone = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('_token', _token)
            })
            ),
            switchMap(newReq => next.handle(newReq).pipe(
                catchError((error) => {
                    // Catch "401 Unauthorized" responses
                    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
                        // Sign out
                        this._authService.signOut();

                        // Reload the app
                        location.reload();
                    }
                    return throwError(error);
                })
            ))
        );
    }

    return next.handle(reqClone).pipe(
        catchError((error) => {
            // Catch "401 Unauthorized" responses
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
                // Sign out
                this._authService.signOut();

                // Reload the app
                location.reload();
            }

            return throwError(error);
        })
    );

}
```

**cloud function**

```
    export const infoEmployee = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    corsHandler(request, response, async () => {
        if (request.method === "GET") {
            if (request.header("_token") !== undefined) {
                const token: any = request.header("_token");
                return admin
                    .auth()
                    .verifyIdToken(token)
                    .then(async (decodedToken) => {
                        const _timeServer = firestore.Timestamp.now();
                        const _timeUser = decodedToken.iat;
                        const _lvl = decodedToken.lvl;
                        if (_timeServer.seconds - _timeUser > 10 && _lvl < 4) {
                            return response.status(401).send({
                                status: 401,
                                subcode: 4,
                                value: "/expired-request-token",
                                fullDescription: "/expired",
                            });
                        } else {
                            const uid: any = request.query.uidUser;
                            const lvl: any = request.query.lvlUser;
                            if (uid === null || uid === undefined ||
                                lvl === null || lvl === undefined) {
                                return response.status(401).send({
                                    status: 401,
                                    subcode: 2,
                                    value: "/invalid-request-params",
                                    fullDescription: "/invalid",
                                });
                            }

                            // body of my function
                        }
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        response.status(401).send(
                            {
                                status: 401,
                                subcode: 3,
                                value: "/invalid-request-token",
                                fullDescription: err,
                            });
                    });
            } else {
                return response.status(401).send({
                    status: 401,
                    subcode: 2,
                    value: "/invalid-request-header",
                    fullDescription: "/invalid",
                });
            }
        } else {
            return response.status(401).send({
                status: 401,
                subcode: 1,
                value: "/invalid-request-method",
                fullDescription: "/invalid",
            });
        }
    });
});
```

PS: firebase does not return me what went wrong.

**Edit #1**

My function returns:

- Error (401), subcode (3), code (invalid-request-token), if I send it 2 parameters.
- Error (401), subcode (2) code (invalid-request-params), if I send only one parameter.

Comment: I don't have time to have a deep look, but `{lvlUser, uidUser}` is sticking out to me. It should be `{lvlUser: lvl, uidUser: uid}`. Also `req.headers.set('_token', _token)` is mutating the original request, not the clone. Use `reqClone.headers.set('_token', _token)` (although, you should use `Authorization: Bearer <_token>` instead).

Comment: Hi @raulabad, Could you please try to setup logging on your code and revert the logs to us. You can check [Report errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors) for more information.

Comment: It is something strange what has happened to me, I have returned to generate the function with another name and in another file and it executes correctly, I do not know what has happened and I can no longer replicate the error.

Even so thanks for the help and also the suggestions, I do not know how to leave this question, because although I solved it, I did not discover the reason for the error if the only thing I changed was to move the function and changes the name.

Comment: @samthecodingman As for Bearer, when we have a stable version of the project that is being developed believe me that is the first thing that will be changed among other things that will be refactored from the project, because changing it at this point would take us a time that we do not have much and unfortunately almost all the functions that we deploy are like that.